# How was Spock able to see destruction of Vulcan without getting destroyed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

In *Star Trek (2009)*, when Vulcan was destroyed by Red Matter black hole, Spock (prime) was able to see it with naked eye.

What's the size of Vulcan and how far away it is from Vega that the same black hole didn't destroy Vega?

Some real world data to draw analogy: We can see nearest planets Mars and Venus with naked eye, but they look like other stars in night sky (except they don't blink). We can see the Moon pretty good sized and from the Moon, Earth can be seen with decent size, but Earth and Moon are too much close (If a black hole eats Earth, the Moon won't survive either). From Earth, we can also see Sun, but Sun is very very big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delta Vega is a moon (or possibly a small planet) **in the Vulcan System**, at least according to [this webchat](http://trekmovie.com/2009/05/18/orci-kurtzman-to-answer-fan-questions-at-trekmovie-transcript-of-last-weeks-impromptu-qa/#1828626) with the film's writer, Bob Orci

> **How can Spock observe the destruction of his homeworld from the surface of Delta Vega. Even if Delta Vega wasn’t near the edge of the galaxy, you couldn’t watch the implosion from a neighbouring planet. You couldn’t see Earth from Mars either. Is Delta Vega a Vulcan moon or what?**
>
> **Bob Orci**: *I prefer to think of Delta Vega as being in close orbit (although it could be a moon), but nonetheless, we like to think of that sequence as impressionistic for a general audience. In other words, Nero could’ve beamed Spock prime down to Delta Vega with a telescope or some other type of measuring device to allow Spock to experience the pain of perceiving the destruction of his home world, but that simply isn’t very cinematic.*

---

Its similarity in name to the [Delta Vega](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Delta_Vega) seen in the Original Series is a [mere coincidence](http://trekmovie.com/2009/04/30/interview-roberto-orci-alex-kurtzman/):

> For the Trek fans, this film includes many little references. For
> example you have Kirk dropped off on the planet Delta Vega, which was
> seen in second Star Trek pilot. It is a cool reference, but didn’t you
> also fudge canon by ignoring that Delta Vega was way out next to the
> galactic barrier.
>
> **Orci:** *True. Yeah we did. We moved the planet to suit our purposes. The
> familiarity of the name seemed more important as an Easter egg, than a
> new name with no importance.*

Comment: Messages moved to chat.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - It'll be a very one-sided conversation

Comment: Which messages? What discussion was moved to chat?

Comment: @thomas - About whether delta vega is a moon  or a planet